# How to adjust the line width of colour in geom_box for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As title, I think the default line width for the border of geom_box is a bit too thick, is there a way of modifying it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the size aesthetic?

Comment: You get size legend with that dont you?

Comment: Not unless you are mapping a variable to the aesthetic.